# How to take the node reference field from views

Tags: views

I have added images through image content type and tagged the node to article content type nodes using node reference , while getting the article credentials through views , i cant figure out how to take the images from the tagged node reference field through views .

some option only avail to get the node reference field in views .
1)Title. 
2)Title link.
3)Full content.
4)Print.

and two more which is not helpful for me .

Here i need to get a image from image content type which is tagged in article content type through node reference .

Anyone help for this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is set up a relationship, as the image itself isn't the node reference, rather a field in that node.  So, you go into Views and after setting it up to grab your article fields, you then set up a relationship, and there, you select that node reference field from your article type.  Then, in fields, you go and select that image field, and there, you use that relationship.  What this does is go and grab that image content type's node id from your article and then using that node id, grab the image field out of it for display.